# Silverlight - Command doesnt execute when checkbox is clicked

Tags: .net, vb.net, silverlight-4.0

I have a check box as so in my xaml

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding ShowCancelledPropertiesCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,160,0"/>
```

and below is the setup for the command in the view model

```
Me.ShowCancelledPropertiesCommand = New DelegateCommand(AddressOf ShowCancelledPropertiesClicked, AddressOf ShowCancelledPropertiesCanExecute)
```

I don't understand why the command isn't being fired?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Does the view model implement INotifyPropertyChanged for instance? And if not, when is the ShowCancelledPropertiesCommand propery value set?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a twoway-binding to the IsChecked property of the checkbox.

```
IsChecked="{Binding somePropertyInViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}
```

And in the viewmodel, put some logic into the property.

```
public bool somePropertyInViewModel
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
```